# Ubuntu Installer does not recognize existing partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

**History of my laptop:** Acer E1-572 with Windows 8.1 preinstalled. I then dual booted with ubuntu without any problems. Then I came across a booting problem which I resolved by reinstalling ubuntu over all previous OS's. Now I want to dual boot Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu.

**Additional Notes:** I installed Windows 8.1 in Legacy Boot (accidentally forget to toggle to UEFI). I hope this isn't a problem.

**Primary Issue**
I successfully installed Windows 8.1 and originally apportioned it all of my laptop's HDD storage (~1T). I then shrank the partition by half and the remaining space is designated "unallocated", according to 'disk management' program.

When I tried to install Ubuntu 14 by booting the installer from USB, I noticed that the installer did not recognize any other partitions.

Running `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`  in Ubuntu trial gave the output:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid MBR and GPT. Which do you want to use?
 1 - MBR
 2 - GPT
 3 - Create blank GPT

Your answer: 1
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 574C6658-FDC9-4406-81EB-B50CB31B0BDC
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1024007533 sectors (488.3 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          718847   350.0 MiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
   2          718848       929519615   442.9 GiB   0700  Microsoft basic data
```